# Why is Android Studio complaining about android:layout_width and layout_height in my simple menu?

Tags: android

I have an app that builds just fine when I build it with `ant`.  But when I import the app into Android Studio, it gives me this error message. Geezzz I really wish I could cut-n-paste text from Android Studio :( so please excuse my screen shot.

[image]

Here's my menu.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Single menu item
         Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
    -->
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_exit"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="Exit" />
</menu>
```

Comment: The IDE it's complaining because you put your menu file inside the layout folder so the IDE thinks that is a layout file. Put the file in the res/menu folder.

Comment: I imported the "project" into Android Studio.  I guess I made the mistake of assuming it would put things where it wants them. ;) But I did what you said and that fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Luksprog's comment The IDE it's complaining because you put your menu file inside the layout folder so the IDE thinks that is a layout file.

```
You should put menu file under res/menu/menu.xml
```

For more details about menu resource

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html